# No space left on device error, but df reports as more space available

Tags: debian, disk-space-utilization, session, inode, tmp

My PHP sessions on my Debian webserver using Apache2 with `mod_php` seem to be failing randomly, saying that there’s no space to write them:

```
sudo tail -60 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Fri Jan 30 15:55:35 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(/tmp/sess_555555555555555555, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in /path/to-first-session-use/core/bootstrap.php on line 18
```

When I try to:

```
ls /tmp
```

It just hangs forever, so that’s bad.

But when I check free space, and check that inode usage is reasonable...

```
$ df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             150G  121G   22G  85% /
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M   16K   10M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm

$ df -i

Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            19922944 11143605 8779339   56% /
tmpfs                 513524       4  513520    1% /lib/init/rw
udev                  513524     135  513389    1% /dev
tmpfs                 513524       3  513521    1% /dev/shm
```

The numbers seem fine.  Sure, 85% is more than I’d like, but it's not 99% or anything.

I was suspecting that it was a problem due to not rebooting the machine for 5 years and maybe the creation of a lot of small files but the inode info that I’m getting kinda contradicts this.  Where should I investigate instead?

**Edit:**

`ls -l /`

```
drwxrwxrwt   4 root root 692M Feb  1 11:09 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 4.0K Jan  1  2013 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root 4.0K Oct  7  2010 var/
...etc
```

Comment: Do you use Plesk?

Comment: What webserver do you use?

Comment: @utrecht This is on a Debian server.

Comment: Ok, but what webserver, e.g., apache2?

Comment: @utrecht Ah, yes, apache2 on this server.

Comment: The output from `ls -l /` would be useful. In particular it will show how large the `/tmp` directory has grown. (That is the size of the directory itself, not the files within it.)

Comment: @kasperd Added that info to the original post.  And it is indeed ...insane in terms of comparitive size. I'm not really sure what to do with that information, though.

Comment: @Kzqai The output from `ls -l /` confirms that `/tmp` is way larger than it should be. With that confirmed my recommendation is to delete `/tmp`, recreate it, and reboot. Like suggested in the answer by JakeGould.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that the `/tmp/` directory itself is filled with stale PHP sessions that are not getting cleaned up; meaning the source of the issues might be isolated to the `/tmp/` directory itself. If that is the case I would just remove all `/tmp/sess_*` files. First, list all of the `sess_*` files like this:

```
ls -la /tmp/sess_*
```

Or you can get count with `wc` like this:

```
ls -la /tmp/sess_* | wc -l
```

Now once you get some confirmation there is some insane number of files there, go ahead and run this command to delete the `/tmp/sess_*` files:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/sess_*
```

And the ephemeral session files will be blown away.

But another brute force—but relatively safe—way to deal wit this is to blow away the `/tmp` directory itself, recreate the `/tmp` directory and reboot the server.

Since the `/tmp` directory is basically a coding holding pen for cached material, there is nothing valid that should be in there. So my best advice is to run the following command to remove & rebuidl the `/tmp` directory.

```
rm -rf /tmp && mkdir /tmp/ && chown root:root /tmp && chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Now that one liner is basically a list of shell commands connected by `&&` that will first delete `/tmp`, recreate `/tmp`, change the ownership of `/tmp` back to `root:root` and then set proper permissions to the `/tmp` directory. If you wish you can run each command one by one if you feel safer doing it that way.

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp 
sudo mkdir /tmp
sudo chown root:root /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Once that is done, I would recommend rebooting the server. Things should be calm cleared up again.

Comment: *nods*  I'll try this approach sometime next week.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete /tmp directly, same as I wasn't able to ls /tmp, but I was able to mount the filesystem temporarily elsewhere and -then- it allowed me to delete & remake the /tmp directory.  I just mv'ed the old directory to /tmp_damaged since I actually wasn't able to rm & delete it either.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes damaged file system can do effects like it - for example when directory /tmp is damaged. Or - when there is to much files.

For "quick" fix:

```
mv /tmp /tmp.xxx
mkdir /tmp
chmod a+rwxt /tmp
```

If that help - try reboot system and fsck root file system. If it's ok - just remove /tmp.xxx directory.

Another possibility is - when /tmp is "other" partition or tmpfs (seen on linux vservers) - but it's not show by df (because df get list of partitions from /etc/mtab file which sometimes is not correct).
Try check disk space directly on tmp by command:

```
df /tmp
df -i /tmp
```

Other option which usually helps with sessions - it using other session mechanism. If you have a lot of temporary sessions, which doesn't need to be very persistent - i would you recommend using memcache for session storing. Configuration it very simple - you must install php-memcache, memcached and then in php.conf configure:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path="tcp://server:port?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
```

Then - sessions will be stored in memcache up to defined size. over it - oldest will be automaticly removed.

Answer (score 1):

For me, changing fs.inotify.max_user_watches did the trick.

```
root@grostruc:/# service ssh restart
Error: No space left on device
root@grostruc:/# sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 65536
root@grostruc:/# sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=262144
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 262144
root@grostruc:/# service ssh restart
```

Fix changed value in /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: That sounds pretty peculiar any clue why that happened?

Comment: Huh, crashplan started this issue for me and this solved it. Thanks! Does this have a significant performance change? I had just over 8k before and going up to 262k seems drastic but good enough for me

Comment: Update this did not fix it.